# saving excel in xml format with picture

Tags: xml, excel, ms-office

I've created an excel spreadsheet and added a picture there, then I've saved this spreadsheet in XML Spreadsheet 2003 format. when I open my xml format, picture dissapears. How can I save spreadsheet in xml format with picture? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unfortunately .xml just won't support images when saved from excel

Comment: Thanks, so how can I add there picture? In MS Word, when I add picture in header, it is saved. Is there any way to do this in excel?

Answer (score -1):

Well you can add a header and footer in excel, i haven't tested it with pictures but this should work in the same way as word

[image]